# How to add data from database as events to fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, json, flask, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-6

I want to add appointments from my database as events into fullcalendar. Right now the calendar renders, but events do not appear in it.

This is my html code(only the calendar related part):

```
<head>
    <title>Calendar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@6.1.8/index.global.min.js'></script>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
              var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
              var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
                headerToolbar: {
                  left: 'prev,next',
                  center: 'title',
                  right: 'timeGridWeek,timeGridDay', },
                  events: '/appointments',

              });
    
              calendar.render();
            });
    
        </script>
</head>
```

this is the appointments route code:

```
@app.route('/appointments')
def get_appointments():
    appointments = Appointment.query.all()
    appointments_data = []

    for appointment in appointments:
        appointment_data = {
            'title': appointment.doctor,
            'start': appointment.date.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M'),
            'end': (appointment.date + timedelta(minutes=appointment.appointment_duration)).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M'),
        }
        appointments_data.append(appointment_data)

    return jsonify(appointments_data)
```

I have tried some solution from the web, but I did not find any that would resolve my problem. I am fairly new to fullcalendar, so if I am doing something fundamentally wrong, please let me know

Comment: This looks like broadly the right approach. What debugging have you done? For example have you checked that the AJAX call to `/appointments` succeeds? What JSON does it return in the raw Response? Or is there some kind of error? Use your browser's Console and Network tools to help you investigate this. Please [edit] the question to show your findings.